# Regex to match everything before a word. To be used in nant script

Tags: regex, nant

I was writing some build scripts for my project. I wanted a regex pattern which can match everything before a particular word. For eg: My script looks like this

```
Create Table ABC(
id int(50)
)

--//@UNDO

Drop table ABC
```

I want to match everything before --//@UNDO using [nant regex task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/regex.html). How do I implement it??

I also want it to match everything in the file if --//@UNDO is not present in the file. I am not getting a way around

Comment: You want only the regex or everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
<loadfile file="${filePathAndName}" property="file.contents" />
    <property name="fileHasUndo" value="${string::index-of(file.contents, '--//@UNDO')}" />
    <choose>
      <when test="${fileHasUndo ==  '-1' }">
          <echo file="${file}" append="true" message="${file.contents}" />
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <regex pattern="(?'sql'[\s\S]*)--\/\/@UNDO[\s\S]*"  input="${file.contents}" options="Multiline"/>
        <echo file="${file}" append="true" message="${sql}" />
      </otherwise>
    </choose>
```

I found the index of --//@UNDO. And depending on its presence I am doing a choose when.. Solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern:

```
(?'str'.*?)--//@UNDO
```

The result will be in str.

Comment: Looks like Nant lets you use .Net RegEx options, you will need to give it the the Singleline (i.e. dot-matches-all) for the above RegEx to work.

Comment: @lxx no i guess you have to add the multiline option

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match the text before the string (and not the string itself) you will need to use a lookahead.

```
.*?(?=--//@UNDO)
```

Needing to specify Singleline still applies.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the NAnt target:

```
<target name="go">
  <loadfile
    file="C:\foo\bar.sql"
    property="content" />
  <regex
    pattern="(?'content'.*)--//@UNDO"
    input="${content}"
    options="Singleline"
    failonerror="false" />
  <echo message="${content}" />
</target>
```

Notice that property `content` is preset with the complete file content in case that `--//@UNDO` is not present in file.